# Cannot find module web3

Tags: javascript, node-modules, web3js

I simply am trying to import web3 to my project and for whatever reason I cannot seem to resolve the issue I am facing. The relevant code is posted below:

**Example.js**

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
console.log('hi');
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "inbox",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "ganache-cli": "^6.12.2",
    "mocha": "^9.1.2",
    "solc": "^0.4.17",
    "web3": "^1.7.2"
  }
}
```

I'll get the preliminary questions out of the way:

- Yes, I have run "npm install web3"
- Yes, I have tried deleting the node_modules folder and package-lock.json file and re-running "npm install"
- Yes, I have tried switching to running "npm install ethereum/web3.js"

When running "node Example.js", I get the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/Users/username/project/node_modules/web3/lib/index.js
```

After looking through my node_modules folder, I found that the actual path to the index.js file of the web3 folder is: /Users/username/project/node_modules/web3/**src**/index.js

I am unsure why node is looking for a 'lib' folder when all the web3 packages in node_modules have 'src' folders. In case anyone is wondering, I am running npm v8.6.0 and node v16.14.2 (also tried with node v14.17.2 and got same errors).

Answer (score 0):

When you see this error message, usually means your `web3` installation was `failed/uncompleted`. the path `node_modules/web3/lib/` exists in successful installation.

I guess some tools are missing in your environment.

Comment: Ah gotcha. Any suggestions for what to try?